# Grouping and the adding column to a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table of a few columns:

```
Sub_Sample <- select(Sample,Month,permno,Return,ExcessReturn,MktCapFirm,Size,MktCapStock,Momentum,
                 BM,lnBM,Beta)
```

I want to winsorize the MktCapFirm column on a monthly basis at the .5% and .995%. So for each value in the MktCap column, I want to winsorize it based on the .05% and .995% of a given month's value. I am using the following code:

```
Sub_Sample<-Sub_Sample[,list(MktCapFirm_Win = Winsorize(MktCapFirm,probs = c(0.005, 0.995), na.rm = T)),by=c("Month")]
```

But this returns only two columns, whereas I want to add the MktCapFirm_Win columns to my original Sub_Sample data.table.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the walrus `:=` assignment with data table:

```
Sub_Sample[ , MktCapFirm_Win := Winsorize(MktCapFirm, probs=c(0.005, 0.995), na.rm = T)), by=c("Month")]
```

Comment: Yes.  The `list(newvar = calculation), by=byvar` style aggregates your data into a new "collapsed" dataset whereas the `newvar := calculation, by=byvar` style adds newvar to the current dataset without changing anything about the current dataset.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 Sub_Sample %>%
     group_by(Month) %>%
     mutate(MktCapFirm_Win = Winsorize(MktCapFirm, probs=c(0.005, 0.995),
           na.rm = TRUE))
```